# CasperJS - Scraper not navigating to the next page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

The following code is a simple scraper written in CasperJS.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var url = casper.cli.get(0);
var page1 = casper.cli.get(1);
var page2 = casper.cli.get(2);
//console.log(page2);
var proxy = casper.cli.get(3);

//alert(page1);

var exp = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(exp);

var baseUrl = url;

//console.log(baseUrl);

var nextBtn = "a.navigation-button.next";

var allLinks = [];

casper.start(baseUrl);

casper.waitForSelector(nextBtn, processPage);

casper.run();

function processPage() {
  for (var i = page1; i < page2; i = i + 1) {
      console.log(i);
    var pageData = this.evaluate(getPageData);
    allLinks = allLinks.concat(pageData);



  if (!this.exists(nextBtn)) {
    return;
  };

  this.thenClick(nextBtn).then(function() {
      //this.echo(i);
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    //this.wait(1000);
  });
};
}

function getPageData(){
  //return document.title;

  var links = document.getElementsByClassName('pro-title');
  links = Array.prototype.map.call(links,function(link){
    return link.getAttribute('href');
  });
  return links;
};


casper.then(function(){
  //require('utils').dump(allLinks);
  this.each(allLinks,function(self,link){
      if (link.match(regex)) {
    self.thenOpen(link,function(a){
      jsonObj = {};
      jsonObj.title = this.fetchText('a.profile-full-name');

      jsonObj.services = this.getHTML('div.info-list-text span:nth-child(2) span');
      jsonObj.services = jsonObj.services.replace(/&amp;/g,"and");  

      jsonObj.location = this.getHTML('div.pro-info-horizontal-list div.info-list-label:nth-child(3) div.info-list-text span');
      //jsonObj.contact = this.fetchText('span.pro-contact-text');
      jsonObj.description = this.getHTML('div.profile-about div:nth-child(1)');  
      //jsonObj.description.replace(/\s/g, '');   

      //require('utils').dump(jsonObj);
      //jsonObj.description = jsonObj.description.replace(/[\t\n]/g,"");   

      //jsonObj = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, '\t');
      //console.log(i);
      require('utils').dump(jsonObj);
    });
      };
  });
});
```

I am executing this script as follows,

`casperjs scraping.js http://www.houzz.com/professionals/c/Chicago--IL/p/15 1 3`

The first CLI argument is the starting URL. The second and third arguments are the starting and ending page numbers of the scrape.

I am able to extract data from the first page, but I don't understand why I am not able to extract data from any of the consequent pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix synchronous and asynchronous code like this in `processPage`. The loop is immediately executed, but the click and the loading of the next page happens asynchronously. The evaluation of the page has to be done asynchronously:

```
function processPage() {
    for (var i = page1; i < page2; i = i + 1) {
        this.then(function(){
            console.log(i);
            var pageData = this.evaluate(getPageData);
            allLinks = allLinks.concat(pageData);

            if (!this.exists(nextBtn)) {
                return;
            }

            this.thenClick(nextBtn).then(function() {
                this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
            });
        });
    };
}
```