# Variable has a different value inside the thenOpen function

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am building a web scraper using CasperJS. I am trying to scrape 3 pages. Each page has 15 links I want to scrape.

In the following code snippet, all the links I want to scrape are collected in the `allLinks` array. Its length is 45. When I log the array, I see all the links I want to scrape correctly. I then iterate over each link and visit the page. When I log `link` (contains each link), I can still see all the 45 links as expected. However, when I log `link` inside the `thenOpen` function, I only see links from the first page. So, it only logs 15 links. It doesn't log any links from page2 and page3.

```
casper.then(function(){
  this.each(allLinks,function(self,link){

    console.log("Getting all the links that need to be visited");
    console.log(allLinks);

    console.log("Getting each link");
    console.log(link);

    this.thenOpen(link,function(a){
      console.log("Inside function that extracts data");
      console.log(link);
    });
  });
});
```

Following is the complete code.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var url = casper.cli.get(0);
console.log(url);

var page2 = casper.cli.get(1);
console.log(page2);

jsonObj = { data : [] };

//var url = 'http://www.houzz.com/professionals/c/Nashville--TN/p/15';
var webPage = require('webpage');
zapTitle = [];
zapContact = [];
zapServices = [];
var page = webPage.create();
var nextBtn = "a.navigation-button.next";

var allLinks = [];

casper.start(url);

casper.waitForSelector(nextBtn, processPage);

casper.run();

function processPage() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= page2; i = i + 1) {
        this.then(function(){
            console.log(i);
            var pageData = this.evaluate(getPageData);
            allLinks = allLinks.concat(pageData);
            console.log(allLinks);

            if (!this.exists(nextBtn)) {
                return;
            }

            this.thenClick(nextBtn).then(function() {
                this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
            });
        });
    };
}

function getPageData(){
  //return document.title;
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName('pro-title');
  links = Array.prototype.map.call(links,function(link){
    return link.getAttribute('href');
  });
  return links;
}

casper.then(function(){
  this.each(allLinks,function(self,link){
    console.log("Inside the each function");
    console.log(link);
    this.thenOpen(link,function(a){
      console.log("Inside function that extracts data");
      console.log(link);

      var description = this.fetchText('div.profile-about div:nth-child(1)');
      description = description.replace(/[\t\n]/g,"");

      var name = this.getHTML('div.pro-info-horizontal-list div.info-list-label:nth-child(2) div.info-list-text');
      name = name.replace(/[<b>Contact</b>: ]/g,"");

      jsonObj.data.push({ 
                "title" : this.fetchText('a.profile-full-name'),
                "contact" : this.fetchText('div.profile-about div:nth-child(1)'),
                "services"  : this.getHTML('div.info-list-text span:nth-child(2) span'),
                "name" : name,
                "location" : this.getHTML('div.pro-info-horizontal-list div.info-list-label:nth-child(3) div.info-list-text span'),
                "description" : description,
                "reviews" : this.getHTML('div.pro-rating a span.pro-review-string span')
            });

       casper.open('https://zapier.com/hooks/catch/29s1m6/', {
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            "title" : this.fetchText('a.profile-full-name'),
                "contact" : this.getHTML('div.pro-contact-methods span.pro-contact-text:nth-child(2)'),
                "services"  : this.getHTML('div.info-list-text span:nth-child(2) span'),
                "name" : name,
                "location" : this.getHTML('div.pro-info-horizontal-list div.info-list-label:nth-child(3) div.info-list-text span'),
                "description" : description,
                "reviews" : this.getHTML('div.pro-rating a span.pro-review-string span')
        }
    });



    }).then(function() {
        console.log(jsonObj.data.length);
        //console.log(jsonObj);
        if (jsonObj.data.length == 13) { 
            console.log(jsonObj.data[13].title);
    }
        /*for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.data.length; i = i + 1 ) {
            console.log(i);
            console.log("zaptitle");
                //zapTitle.push(jsonObj.data[i]);
                console.log(jsonObj.data[i].title);
            //}
        }*/
        //require('utils').dump(jsonObj.data[2].title);
        //require('utils').dump(jsonObj);

        //require('utils').dump(jsonObj.data[8]);
        //require('utils').dump(zapTitle);

        for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.data.length; i = i + 1 ) {
            zapServices.push(jsonObj.data[i].services);
        }

        /*casper.open('https://zapier.com/hooks/catch/29s1m6/', {
            method: 'post',
            data: {"title" : zapTitle,
            //"contact" : zapContact,
            "services" : zapServices
        }*/


    });
 });
});
```

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. `link` is "closed", so it must be the same in `this.thenOpen(link` and in both `console.log(link);`. Perhaps you removed some code that might be the culprit.

Comment: `link` is not the same in both the `console.logs`. Please take a look at the complete code in my question. @ArtjomB.

Comment: Looks fine to me. I see you've used [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35428293/1816580).

Comment: Yes I have, but `link` is not the same in both the `console.logs`. That's why I am only able to extract data from the first page. I don't see any data from the remaining two pages. I am passing 3 as an argument so the value of `page2` is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`casper.getHTML(selector)` fails and exits the script if it doesn't find the element you are looking for ([code reference](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L1152)). Of course, this error is hidden if you're using PhantomJS 2.0 or 2.1.

The culprit is `"location" : this.getHTML('div.pro-info-horizontal-list div.info-list-label:nth-child(3) div.info-list-text span'),` on the [12th page](http://www.houzz.com/pro/crowellinteriors/crowell-co-interiors), because it doesn't exist. You need to check whether the selector exists (e.g. with `casper.exists(selector)`) before trying to access it.

This is what a [little `console.log` debugging](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/916eda32f0e16f987a00) can accomplish.

Comment: Also, since you know which is the page that the script stopped on, you could have looked at it more closely to see how it differs from other pages.